# How to plot the distribution of each in feature in cancer dataset

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, python-ggplot

I want to get the distribution of each features in cancer dataset using ggplot but its giving me error.

```py
#pip install plotnine
from plotnine import ggplot
from plotnine import *
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

for i in cancer.feature_names:
    ggplot(cancer.data)+aes(x=i)+geom_bar(size=10)
```

This is the error message i got

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Are you ready to explore matplotlib or seaborn for plotting?

Comment: neither matplotlib nor seaborn but ggplot from plotnine library , actualy ggplot is a feature for R, although it is for R we can use in python also.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for that. Here is an example of plotting the distribution of each in feature in cancer dataset by target:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer    
# loading data
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
data = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target']],
                  columns= np.append(cancer['feature_names'], ['target']))

df = data.melt(['target'], var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='cols', hue="target", palette="Set1", col_wrap=4)
g = (g.map(sns.distplot, "vals", hist=True, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from plotnine import ggplot
from plotnine import *
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer=load_breast_cancer()
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.DataFrame(cancer.data,columns=cancer.feature_names)


for i in data.columns:
    print(ggplot(data)+aes(x=i)+geom_density(size=1))
    print(ggplot(data)+aes(x=i)+geom_bar(size=10))
```